# Windows Service installs app via msiexec. The app is installed, but it is not listed in 'uninstall a program' list. Why?

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer

I have Windows Service running as LocalSystem account. The Service calls msiexec with the following arguments:

```
string commandLineArguments = "/package C:\\install.msi /quiet /norestart ";
start.Arguments = (commandLineArguments);
```

The msiexec returns Success and moves files to "C:\Program Files", but the app is not listed in an "uninstall a program" list, therefore, when I run the installer manually, there is no option to repair or remove, but to install the software again. Why?

I understand it is probably because the service runs in the system context and not the user context. How I can instruct MSI to perform the installation for the current user?

How can I uninstall software installed by service?

Comment: What happens if you run the installer normally (i.e. not from the service)?

Comment: It appears in the list and I am able to remove it.

Comment: A log file of the installation process could help. For now only guessing is possible.

Comment: I understand it may be because Windows Service runs in a different context than the current user, but I don't know how to make this installation for the current user.

Comment: It's a widespread practice to install msi under a System context (especially in enterprise) so it shouldn't be an issue for a valid installer.

Comment: What it does depends a lot on the specific MSI and the values of [some properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/allusers). Are you the author of the MSI? It may be ending up doing a pre-user install under the service's account rather than a per-machine install.

Comment: Yes, I am the author. It does use the System context. When I see the log file of the MSI installation done by service, most paths start with C:\WINDOWS\system32 whereas when I do the installation manually they start with C:\Users\Chris\
I already tried different properties for MSI arguments - with ALLUSERS and MSIINSTALLPERUSER, none of them worked.

Comment: Then everything points to it being installed per-user - `C:\Users\Chris` is *your* profile path, built-in service accounts use `%System32%` as their profile paths. And that's why you wouldn't see uninstall options for it when looking from your account.

Comment: "How I can instruct MSI to perform the installation for the current user?" - for services, it's helpful to bear in mind that, at any time, there may be 0, 1 or *multiple* users logged into the machine. "*the* current user"? - no such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Windows Service that runs as a LocalSystem installs the software, it is installed in the System context, as montonero mentioned in the comment.
If the MSI file to be installed has the property InstallScope set to perUser or it does not have set InstallScope property at all (then the default is perUser), the installed software will not be visible in the uninstall list (Thank you Damien_The_Unbeliever).

I tested this by providing the service with two MSI files. One with set InstallScope to perUser and the other set to perMachine. Only perMachine installation can be visible in the uninstall list.

Passing ALLUSERS and MSIINSTALLPERUSER properties to MSIEXEC did not override the properties set in MSI files.